# when are level sets a finite collection of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let  $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $S=[x,y]$. I am looking for references on the following property.

There is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall v\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $a_1\leq...\leq a_{2k}\in S$, such that $\{z:f(z)=v\}=\cup^k_{n=1}[a_{2n-1},a_{2n}]$.

Basically the level sets of $f$ are a collection of intervals where the number of intervals are uniformly bounded.

Would smoothness work? I suppose the issue is that smooth humps can get infinitesimal.

Answer (score 0):

Smoothness itself won't work, consider something like $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \sin(1/x) e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. This is (I think) smooth at $0$ (and also of course everywhere else too), but $f^{-1}(0)$ is infinite set.

Something like $C^1$ + the first derivative has only finitely many zeroes might probably work though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think your answer works, but it's basically assuming the conclusion. "the first derivative has only finitely many zeroes " would already be a property that would work if I assumed it for $f$. Also it would be too strong for what I want, because this precludes the constant function.

Comment: I don't think what you want can really be shown to be equivalent to some other natural property. The question here is what exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the big picture?

Comment: The property seems very natural. More generally it would correspond to when level sets are a finite set of connected components. Would something like the following work: all derivatives are bounded uniformly by some constant? I do not think this is true about your example.